# Passing a Paramiko connection SFTPFile as input to a dask.dataframe.read_parquet

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, dask, parquet

I tried to pass class `paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile` instead of file URL for `pandas.read_parquet` and it worked fine. But when I tried the same with Dask, it threw an error. Below is the code I tried to run and the error I get. How can I make this work?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import parmiko
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
source_file=sftp_client.open(str(parquet_file),'rb')
full_df = dd.read_parquet(source_file,engine='pyarrow')
print(len(full_df))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rrrrr\Documents\jackets_dask.py", line 22, in <module>
    full_df = dd.read_parquet(source_file,engine='pyarrow')
  File "C:\Users\rrrrr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py", line 1173, in read_parquet
    storage_options=storage_options
  File "C:\Users\rrrrr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dask\bytes\core.py", line 368, in get_fs_token_paths
    raise TypeError('url type not understood: %s' % urlpath)
TypeError: url type not understood: <paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x0000007712D9A208>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dask does not support file-like objects directly.

You would have to implement their ["file system" interface](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/connect-to-remote-data.html#developer-api).

I'm not sure what is minimal set of methods that you need to implement to allow `read_parquet`. But you definitely have to implement the `open`. Something like this:

```
class SftpFileSystem(object):
    def open(self, path, mode='rb', **kwargs):
        return sftp_client.open(path, mode)

dask.bytes.core._filesystems['sftp'] = SftpFileSystem

df = dd.read_parquet('sftp://remote/path/file', engine='pyarrow')
```

There's actually am implementation of such file system for SFTP in fsspec library:
https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.sftp.SFTPFileSystem

See also [Is it possible to read a .csv from a remote server, using Paramiko and Dask's read_csv() method in conjunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56623297/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Answer (score 1):

The situation has changed, and you can do this now directly with Dask. Paster answer from [Is it possible to read a .csv from a remote server, using Paramiko and Dask's read_csv() method in conjunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623297/is-it-possible-to-read-a-csv-from-a-remote-server-using-paramiko-and-dasks-re)

In the master version of Dask, file-system operations are now using `fsspec` which, along with the previous implementations (s3, gcs, hdfs) now supports some additional [file-systems](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#built-in-implementations), see the mapping to protocol identifiers [`fsspec.registry.known_implementations`](https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/blob/master/fsspec/registry.py#L10).

In short, using a url like "sftp://user:pw@host:port/path" should now work for you, if you install fsspec and Dask from master.